# How do I remove the box shadow below the 'Active' tab and the shadow on the part below it to make it seamless?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF1Sp.png) of what im trying t remove.

```
.tab-selector > .tab-ind {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 2.5em 0;
    width: 200px;
}

.active-tab {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 10px #bebebe,
                inset -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
    }

.lesson-selection {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 10px #bebebe,
                inset -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
}
```

I tried changing box shadows and making it none. Is there a workaround to do this?

Comment: Can you provide your html?